# Optimizando la Detección de Cortocircuitos en Matriz Grande de Átomos: Buscando Estrategias Eficaces

Tags: java, algoritmos, matrices, estructuras-de-datos, eficiencia

Contexto:
Estoy trabajando en un problema de simulación que involucra una matriz de n x n que representa átomos. Cada átomo puede ser conductor o no. La simulación implica transmutar átomos no conductores en conductores y determinar si esto crea un "cortocircuito", definido como una conexión de conductores desde la parte superior hasta la parte inferior de la matriz.

Problema:
El algoritmo actual para detectar cortocircuitos es ineficiente para matrices grandes (ej. 2000x2000). Necesito optimizarlo para reducir el tiempo de ejecución, idealmente a O(logn) o mejor.
Implementacion del disjoint set

```
    class DisjointSet {
private int[] parent;
private int[] rank;

public DisjointSet(int size) {
    parent = new int[size];
    rank = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        parent[i] = i;
        rank[i] = 0; // Inicializar rangos en 0
    }
}

public int find(int i) {
    if (parent[i] != i) {
        parent[i] = find(parent[i]); // Compresión de caminos
    }
    return parent[i];
}

public void union(int x, int y) {
    int rootX = find(x);
    int rootY = find(y);

    if (rootX != rootY) {
        if (rank[rootX] < rank[rootY]) {
            parent[rootX] = rootY;
        } else if (rank[rootX] > rank[rootY]) {
            parent[rootY] = rootX;
        } else {
            parent[rootY] = rootX;
            rank[rootX]++;
        }
    }
}
public boolean isConnected(int x, int y) {
    return find(x) == find(y);
}
```

}

Algoritmo de busqueda de cortocircuito

```
    private void actualizarBanderasDeConexion(int indice) {
boolean conexionSuperior = false;

// Verificar si es necesario ejecutar el bucle
if (contadorSuperior > 0) {
    for (int k = 0; k < contadorSuperior; k++) {
        int indiceSuperior = getKey(0, transmutadosSuperior[k]);
        if (disjointSet.isConnected(indice, indiceSuperior)) {
            conexionSuperior = true;
            break; // Salir del bucle al encontrar una conexión
        }
    }
}

if (conexionSuperior && contadorInferior > 0) {
    for (int l = 0; l < contadorInferior; l++) {
        int indiceInferior = getKey(n - 1, transmutadosInferior[l]);
        if (disjointSet.isConnected(indice, indiceInferior)) {
            cortocircuito = true;
            break; // Salir del bucle al encontrar una conexión
        }
    }
}
```

}

Union de atomos

```
   private void uniteAdjacentAtoms(int i, int j) {
int index = getKey(i, j);

int[] dx = {-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
int[] dy = {-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1};

for (int k = 0; k < dx.length; k++) {
    int ni = i + dx[k];
    int nj = j + dy[k];
    if (ni >= 0 && ni < n && nj >= 0 && nj < n && esConductor[ni][nj]) {
        disjointSet.union(index, getKey(ni, nj));

    }
}
actualizarBanderasDeConexion(index);
```

}

Transmutacion de atomos

```
     public void RayoCosmico(int i, int j) {
  
    if (!esConductor[i][j]) {
        esConductor[i][j]=true;
        if (i == 0) {
            transmutadosSuperior[contadorSuperior++] = j;
        } else if (i == n - 1) {
            transmutadosInferior[contadorInferior++] = j;
        }
        lastI=i;
        lastJ=j;
        
        
        uniteAdjacentAtoms(i, j);
        
    }
}
```

Estrategia Actual:
Utilizo una estructura de conjunto disjunto (Disjoint Set) para manejar la unión y la búsqueda de átomos conectados. Cuando un átomo se transmuta en conductor, actualizo los conjuntos disjuntos y verifico si hay un cortocircuito. Sin embargo, la verificación del cortocircuito, que requiere revisar todos los átomos de las filas superior e inferior para cada transmutación, se ha convertido en un cuello de botella.

Pregunta:
¿Cómo puedo optimizar este proceso, especialmente la detección de cortocircuitos? ¿Existen estructuras de datos o algoritmos más adecuados para este tipo de problemas que puedan mejorar la eficiencia, especialmente para matrices de gran tamaño?

Nota: no se pueden usar imports cualquier estructura de datos debe ser definida a mano y se puede cambiar cualquier estructura

Comment: Bienvenido. La pregunta será mejor recibida si incluyes el código